# Font Awesome setTimeout function failing to animate (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, settimeout, font-awesome

I am following a very simple code along tutorial and cannot  understand why my font awesome Icon is not transitioning from the first icon (link) to the second (broken link).

The problem seems to be with the setTimeout function within breakChain();. When  setTimeout is lower than 100ms, the second Icon state appears immediately on load. Any higher and the initial icon state appears on load. There is no transition between states ("I do know this code,as is, will only transition once between the initial icon and the second icon")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animated Icons</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#chain {
    font-size: 50px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id='chain' class="fa"></div>
    <script>
    function breakChain() {
        let chain = document.getElementById('chain');
        chain.innerHTML = "&#xf0c1;";

        setTimeout(function() {
            chain.innerHTML = "&#xf127;";
        }, 1000);
    }
    breakChain();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems the new font-awesome replaces your html elements with svg. My guess is when you set your timeout to 1000, font awesome manages to complete the replacement process and at that point you don't have a html element to change. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

Comment: Check this out for possible solutions: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I accidentally brought in the font awesome js instead of a link to the css... oops.

```
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/4.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animated Icons</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#chain {
    font-size: 50px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id='chain' class="fa fas"></div>
    <script>
    function breakChain() {
        let chain = document.getElementById('chain');
        chain.innerHTML = "&#xf0c1;";

        setTimeout(function() {
            chain.innerHTML = "&#xf127;";
        }, 1000);
    }
    breakChain();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```